# What's the probability to get Fire Aspect on a Netherite sword? On a book?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I wonder if it's better value to get Fire Aspect 1 on two swords and merge them or if it's better to have instantly Fire Aspect 2

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! Since this is a Q&A site, please consider accepting the post below if that answered your question.

Answer (score 3):

According to [this Enchantment calculator](https://minecraft.tools/en/enchant.php) (this is for 1.16, but should be still reliable):

[image]

You can have up to 16.2% chance to get Fire Aspect II for a level 30 enchantment, while you have up to 12.3% chance to get Fire Aspect I for a level 21 enchantment.

On the other hand, it's very unlikely to get Fire Aspect II on a book, because, from the same calculator, there's only 1.7% chance to get it:

[image]

So it's easier to get Fire Aspect I on two different swords and then merge them. If you have many spare diamonds (swords). But it's not so hard to find Fire Aspect II.

As a side note, I got lots of Fire Aspect II books fishing, give it a try.